# C++11 std::function const overload ambiguity

Tags: c++11, overloading, std-function, const-correctness

I'm having a problem with a part of a larger program where something that I'd say is not ambiguous is considered ambiguous by both `g++` and `clang++`

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int) {}
    Foo(std::string) {}
    operator int () const { return 42; }
    operator std::string () const { return ""; }

    void foo(std::function<void(Foo&, int)>f);
    void foo(std::function<void(const Foo&, int)>f) const; // xxx

    void foo(std::function<void(const std::string&, Foo&)>f);
    void foo(std::function<void(const std::string&, const Foo&)>f) const;

    void bar() const {
        this->foo([](const Foo&, int){}); // xxx
    }
};
```

I'd expect the invocation of `::foo` made in `bar` to be unambiguously resolved to the const version marked with `xxx`, while instead both compilers complain that the overload resolution is ambiguous:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c -Wall amb.cpp 
amb.cpp: In member function ‘void Foo::bar() const’:
amb.cpp:18:40: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(Foo::bar() const::<lambda(const Foo&, int)>)’ is ambiguous
         this->foo([](const Foo&, int){});
                                        ^
amb.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: void Foo::foo(std::function<void(const Foo&, int)>) const
     void foo(std::function<void(const Foo&, int)>f) const;
          ^
amb.cpp:15:10: note: candidate: void Foo::foo(std::function<void(const std::basic_string<char>&, const Foo&)>) const
     void foo(std::function<void(const std::string&, const Foo&)>f) const;
          ^
```

Why it's not clear which version I want to call? How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Look at the constructor constraints for `std::function`. Both named overloads are permitted. Both produce user-defined conversions, neither of which is better than the other.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not sure I understand. The marked version has an **identical** std::function argument declaration, the other versions don't. Why is that considered a user-defined conversion too?

Comment: Your function argument is a lambda expression, not an expression of type `std::function<void(const Foo&, int)>`. So you need a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some type information is lost when passing from a lambda to an `std::function` object (in particular the argument types).

To be more specific for example a function accepting `std::function<void(int)>` and another accepting `std::function<void(double)>` are considered equally good overloads for a `void` lambda accepting an `int` argument.

For example with

```
#include <functional>

void foo(std::function<void(int)>f);
void foo(std::function<void(double)>f);

void bar() {
    foo([](int){});
}
```

the call in `bar` is considered ambiguous

```
amb2.cpp: In function ‘void bar()’:
amb2.cpp:8:18: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(bar()::<lambda(int)>)’ is ambiguous
     foo([](int){});
                  ^
amb2.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: void foo(std::function<void(int)>)
 void foo(std::function<void(int)>f);
      ^
amb2.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: void foo(std::function<void(double)>)
 void foo(std::function<void(double)>f);
      ^
```

## Workaround

A solution is to explicitly create the proper `std::function` object with:

```
this->foo(std::function<void(const Foo&, int)>([](const Foo&, int){}));
```

Comment: Do you have any more information on why this is? I ran into this problem and had a hell of a time trying to figure it out, since there's not a lot of information on it.

Comment: @Benjamin: Sorry but I'm not a language lawyer and I never tried to implement a C++ front end. Unfortunately closures were missing as a concept in C and they're therefore sort of "bolted on" C++ and quite weird objects (for example each lambda definition is its own unique type even if it has an identical interface). May be these warts are sort of unavoidable because of all the other bolted-on features in the language...

Answer (score 0):

You could make the constructor taking the `std::string` argument `explicit`. That way the compiler can't make an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `Foo`.

Comment: @6502 Then you are going to continue to have an ambiguity, unless you can work around it some other way. By the way, I would consider the need for implicit conversions a design smell, and it will make the code harder read and understand.

Comment: With the change in my answer the code works (and works in the full program too). The need for implicit conversion to/from C++ types is essential (it's basically an implementation of a "typeless" value to support JSON data, so implicit from/to conversion is to make the objects more usable). For sure there's kind of an impedance mismatch between JSON and C++, but I wouldn't call it a smell in this specific case.